# Payments facility in xamarin.forms application

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, payment

I have a xamarin.forms application where i need to implement payments options for users,I thought to implement stripe component but [this](https://components.xamarin.com/view/stripe) is showing as **Dead Link**,is there any other plugin or component to integrate payment in ios application of xamarin.forms and also there are many plugins of braintree and paypal are available,but not getting the way to use them in my application,please help me to achieve payment transactions in app.

Comment: Please note that external payment providers might violate Apples ToS.

Comment: Thanks for responding @PaulKertscher, But i need a payment option,how to do that with out external payment providers?

Comment: It depends on *what* you are billing fore. They don't always violate the terms, but there are conditions under which they do.

Comment: This [link](https://xamarinhelp.com/stripe-in-xamarin/) might help

Comment: @PaulKertscher,My application is about selling food items,so user needs to pay for those items which they orders,will it violate the terms?

Comment: @GeraldVersluis,Thanks for link.

Comment: Selling food should be okay, I think the terms are about digital goods and especially app enhancements.